# How do I create a custom ActiveAdmin filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, ransack

I tried creating a custom filter using ActiveAdmin with Ransack in Rails 4, like this:

1. Create a ransacker in the User class.

   ```
    ransacker :by_group, formatter: proc { |v|
      data = User.with_role(v).map(&:id)
      data.present? ? data : nil
    } do |parent|
      parent.table[:id]
    end
   ```
2. Add it as a filter to my User admin registration.

   ```
    filter :by_group, label: 'By Group', as: :select, collection: proc { Group.where('code not in (?)', ['erroneous']).to_a.map{|p| [p.name, p.code]} }
   ```

However this does not work. When picking an option an clicking FILTER button:

1. The resulting list ignores the filter field (i.e. other filters may apply, but the filter I care about, does not).
2. The search form field reset to value "Any" (other fields do not reset).

My goal:

> Given a set of available Group instances, I want to pick one group by its code, and get the users satisfying User.with_role(code)

What am I missing?

Versions:
Rails 4.2.0
ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2

Comment: Try to change `filter :by_group` to `filter :by_group_in`